# Time-Based IF Statement Not Working

Tags: php

The code below is supposed to initiate CSS based on `if($row["datesubmitted"] > $livetime){`.  The CSS should go into effect if "datesubmitted" is less than 1 hour old.  But it's not working.

Any idea why not?

For comparison, the same code works with the IF statement `if($row["topten"] == 1){`.

**EDIT:** In MySQL, `datesubmitted` is Type = timestamp and Default = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Thanks in advance,

John

```
$livetime = time()-3600;


$result = mysql_query($sqlStr);

$arr = array(); 
echo "<table class=\"samplesrec\">";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $dt = new DateTime($row["datesubmitted"], $tzFrom); 
    $dt->setTimezone($tzTo);

    if($row["datesubmitted"] > $livetime){
```

Comment: Is it possible to compare `DateTime` objects with plain timestamps?

Comment: Perhaps provide us with a complete code snippet so we be sure of what we are debugging?  Can you provide the code up to the end of the while loop?

Comment: is the value of `datesubmitted` an unix timestamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try using strtotime, like this..

`if(strtotime($row["datesubmitted"]) > $livetime)`

it'll work since your $row["datesubmitted"] is a datetime format from mysql..

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datesubmitted) as datesubmitted` in your query and use that value as is (as a timestamp) when comparing to the other timestamp.